# Callback in interface with parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

I'm currently implementing a generic dropdown menu element using Angular (v8.0.1). Therefore, I planned on creating the dropdown with an array of elements of a specific interface such as can be seen below:

```
export interface DropdownSettings {
    title: string;
    callback: (...params: any) => any;
}
```

For each possible dropdown option, an object of the interface is created an passed to the component;

```
public filter_options: DropdownSettings[] = [
    {
        title: 'Date ascending',
        callback: ??
    },
    ...
}
```

Where the options are then passed to the component using a standard input:

```
<dropdown title="Filter"
          [options]="filter_options">
</dropdown>
```

If a user selects an element in the dropdown, the set callback should be called performing some actions on a dataset that is passed. The callback itself is called in the following manner within the dropdown-menu components implementation:

```
elementSelected(callback: (??) => void) {
    callback(??);
    this.toggleVisible();
}
```

The problem that arises is the following and also marked with the questionmarks. Within the callback function I don't have direct access on private member variables, which makes sense since the scope changes. However, I'd also preferably avoid passing, say a huge dataset to the component. This is simply because the dropdown menu itself does not have to have access to this data. Therefore I'd like to specify a function that is marked private or static within the component the dropdown menu is created, meaning, that all operations will be performed within the parent-component itself.

```
private static filterByDate(dataset: Redeem[]): void {
    dataset.sort((a: Redeem, b: Redeem) => {
        a = new Date(a.created_at);
        b = new Date(b.created_at);
        return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    });
}
```

So the main question that arises is: 
How can I specify a callback function in an interface with additional parameters?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear (at least to me) and your code bit doesn't help at all. What do you want to achieve exactly ? Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: currently editing